# Generating build files for different visual studio versions

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, cmake-gui

I recently moved to VS2022 and uninstalled VS2019. However, I need to generate some build files in VS2019. When I try to do so, I get this error

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (project):
  Generator

    Visual Studio 16 2019

  could not find any instance of Visual Studio.
```

So my question is since I currently have VS2022, can I generate VS2019 build files?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So my question is since I currently have VS2022, can I generate VS2019 build files?

No. The generator relies on finding the VS2019 MSBuild in order to work. In general, you can't generate project files for a backend that isn't installed.